# Prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 1$ for $x_n > 0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Given a sequence $x_n$ and the fact that:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 1\\
> x_n > 0\\
> n\in\Bbb N
> $$
>   Prove
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n} = 1
> $$

I'm having some difficulties finishing this proof. I've shown while solving another problem that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = a \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k = a
$$

Using this we may state that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = 1 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k = 1
$$

On the other hand by AM-GM we have that:
$$
\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots x_n}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}
$$

Since $x_n > 0$:
$$
\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots x_n}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n} \ge 0
$$

We know that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots x_n}{n} = 1
$$

Therefore:
$$
1 \ge \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}  \ge 0
$$

My idea was to use Monotone Convergence theorem, but since $x_n$ is only constrained by $x_n > 0$ we can not make any conclusions on the monotonicity of:
$$
y_n = \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}
$$
(or can we?).

Apparently my idea to use MCT is not applicable here. So the question is what would be the proper way to prove the above?

Comment: Can't we say that the average of the logarithms goes to $0?$

Comment: @metamorphy Proving Stolz-Cesaro follows right after this problem. So i may not use it yet.

Comment: But you said you've proved $x_n\to a\implies (1/n)\sum x_k \to a$  Isn't that enough?  We know $\log{x_n}\to 0.$

Comment: @saulspatz you are right, guess I need a rest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the logarithm and use Stolz cesaro to deduce that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\log\sqrt[n]{x_1\dotsb x_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log x_i=\lim_{n\to \infty}\log x_n=0
$$
since $x_n\to 1$ from which the claim follows.

Comment: Thank you, i was missing such an obvious thing

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence defined, for all $n \geq 0$, by$$y_n = \ln(x_n)$$

Obviously $y_n \rightarrow 0$. So by the Cesaro theorem, you have that 
$$\frac{y_1 + ... + y_n}{n} \rightarrow 0$$

That means that 
$$\frac{\ln(x_1 \times ... \times x_n)}{n} \rightarrow 0$$

i.e. 
$$\ln \left( \sqrt[n]{x_1 \times ... \times x_n} \right) \rightarrow 0$$

You deduce that 
$$ \sqrt[n]{x_1 \times ... \times x_n} \rightarrow 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Just for the completeness: we can use the $HM\le GM\le AM$ inequality:
$$
H_n:=\frac{1}{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n {\frac{1}{x_k}}}{n}} \le
\left(\prod_{k=1}^n {x_k}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\le 
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n {x_k}}{n}=:A_n
$$

- $x_n\to 1 \text{ with } x_n>0 \implies \frac{1}{x_n}\to 1$
- <del>Cesaro summation</del> Cauchy's first limit theorem implies that $\frac{1}{H_n}\to 1$ (so $H_n\to 1$ ) and $A_n\to 1$
- apply the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)